# Display Browser specific date/time using extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a database field called CreatedDate which is a timestamp field and holds the date and time. It currently holds the GMT time.

At the moment this field is displayed as it is on the web pages.

We want to amend this to show date/time as per browser local time zone

Can you please let us know how we can do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can represent the universal time as a count of milliseconds since the 1 Jan 1970 epoch **at the server** then you can have the page code construct Date instances at the client using the client time zone, but starting from that UTC reference.  It's the normal behavior of the Javascript Date() constructor:

```
var clientDate = new Date(serverUTC);
```

Now exactly how you get that UTC value depends on your server language. In a JSP page it'd be pretty simple:

```
var clientDate = new Date(<%= whatever.getTheDate().getTime() %>);
```

or

```
var clientDate = new Date(${something.theDate.time});
```

Once you've got the date value as a client-side Javascript Date instance, you can just update the field(s) with the string. There are no built-in Date formatting tools, but the old standard [date.js](http://www.datejs.com) might help with its ".toString()" formatter.